# Maximising $\int_{0}^{T} v(t)\, dt$, subject to constraints $|v(t)| \leq a; v(0)=0; v(T)=0$

Tags: optimization, definite-integrals, calculus-of-variations

Besides those constraints, we know nothing else about $v(t)$. Interpreting the integral as the distance travelled by a particle, a little geometry tells us that the answer should be $aT^{2}/4$

However, I'm interested in knowing whether there's an analytic approach, which hopefully allows for generalisation. I don't have a background in variational calculus, but I do know one variable calculus. Would I be able to maximise the above integral without appeal to variational calculus? If the answer is no, I'd like to know how one would go about doing it with the full machinery.

Comment: Remark by a physicist. Since $aT^2$ is a length and $T$ is a time, the number $a$ denotes an *acceleration*. But the argument of $v$ is a time. Therefore, the expression $v''(a)$ is meaningless. Maybe you meant $v'(0)=a$, which is dimensionally correct ?

Comment: Corrected. Sorry for the initial confusion.

Comment: @MaxisJaisi Did you by any chance mean to impose the condition $\lvert v'(t)\rvert\leqslant a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, $v(t) \le v'_\mathrm{max} t = at$ for all $t$. It follows that $I(v) = \int_0^T v(t) \le aT^2/2$. So this is an upper bound.

This bound cannot be reached. Indeed suppose that you have some $v$ with $v(0) = 0$, $v'(t) \le a$ for all $t$, and $I(v) = a T^2 / 2$. Then $\int_0^T (at - v(t)) dt = 0$; but $at - v(t) \ge 0$, which implies that $v(t) = at$ for all $t$. In particular $v(T) = aT \neq 0$, which means that $v$ does not fulfill your conditions.

The best we can hope for is some sequence of functions $v_n$ such that all the $v_n$ satisfy the conditions and $\int_0^T v_n(t) dt \to aT^2/2$ when $n \to +\infty$. Let $x_n = 1 - 1/n$, then you can for example take the piecewise linear function:
$$v_n(t) = \begin{cases} at & 0 \le t \le x_n \\ \frac{t-T}{x_n-T} x_n & x_n \le t \le 1 \end{cases}$$
and smooth it out to get a differentiable function. Since $\int_0^T v_n(t) dt$, this shows that $aT^2/2$ really is the sup of possible integrals of functions satisfying your conditions.

Comment: @Jonas The question was changed after I posted my answer.

Comment: Indeed, I have removed my comment

Answer (score 2):

If you have $v(0)=v(T)=0$, and $\lvert v'(t)\rvert \leqslant a$ for all $t\in[0,T]$, then the fundamental theorem of calculus ensures, for all $t\in[0,T/2]$, that
$$
v(t)=v(t)-v(0) = \int_0^t v'(t)dt \leqslant at,
$$
and for all $t\in[T/2,T]$, that
$$
v(t) =-(v(T)-v(t))=-\int_t^T v'(t)dt \leqslant a(T-t).
$$

Integrating then yields
$$
\int _0^T v(t) dt\leqslant \frac{1}{4}aT^2.
$$

On the other hand, the choice
$$
v(t)=\begin{cases}
at,&t\in[0,T/2],\\
a(T-t),&t\in[T/2,T],
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies $v(0)=v(T)=0$,
$$
v'(t)=\begin{cases}
a,&t\in[0,T/2),\\
-a,&t\in(T/2,T],
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^T v(t)dt=\frac{1}{4}aT^2.
$$

Note that this choice of $v$ is only piecewise differentiable, so whether or not you agree that $v$ maximizes your functional depends on the class in which you are looking for a maximizer.

Comment: You should retry computing $\int_0^T v(t) dt$, because I find $aT^2/4$. In fact it's not possible to actually reach the maximal value.

Comment: Of course you are right, from the physical motivation of the question I had in mind the condition $\lvert v'(t)\rvert\leqslant a$, but then mixed up the two conditions when I started writing the answer.